# Quickly altering variable highlighted by IntelliSense

Tags: visual-studio, caret

When I put caret next to a variable, IntelliSense highlights all occurences of this variable (within its scope).

1. How can I swiftly (using shortcuts) edit its name?
2. Can I have multiple cursors next to all those variables?

pic related

[image]

Comment: For your first question, just start editing the name - you'll get a "lightbulb" popup with the option to rename.